# Find type of square (f (g x)) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hello I have a problem with finding type for square (f (g x)). Here is what I have.

```
square :: Int -> Int
{x : b} |- g x :: (b -> c) -> c
f :: (((b -> c) -> c) -> d) -> d
```

I am a bit confused if it's correct and what now. `d` must be an `Int` as well as whole expression `(((b -> c) -> c) -> d)` but I feel like I did sth wrong here...

Comment: Where are you getting your type for `f` from? Same question for the type of `g x`. Also, why are you looking at either of those? If all you want to know is the type of `square (f (g x))` and you already know that `square :: Int -> Int` then `square (f (g x))` must be `Int` assuming everything typechecks, regardless of what the types of `f`, `g` or `x` are.

Comment: true but i need type of whole expression (most general type) not just the type of its result

Comment: The most general type of the expression is `Int`.

Comment: @heisenberg7584 In almost all modern type systems, the type of a whole expression is *less general* than the type of its result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overgeneralizing in some way I don't quite follow.

If you are stating that `x :: b`, then if you can apply `g` to `x`, `g :: b -> c` for some type `c`.

Similarly, since you can apply `f` to `g x`, then `f :: c -> d` for some type `d`; it's argument type must be the same as the return type of `g`.

Finally, you know that `square :: Int -> Int` and that you can apply `square` to the return value of `f`. That means `f :: c -> Int` by unifying the return type of `f` with the argument type of `square`.

That's as far as you can go, though:

```
square :: Int -> Int
f :: c -> Int
g :: b -> c
x :: b
```

You then know that `g x :: c` and `f (g x) :: Int`, meaning `square (f (g x)) :: Int` as well.